# Use labels by which *not* to group in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have written a code that evaluates sums like

```
\sum_i a_{i,j}
```

(read "sum a over all values of i")
by creating a `pd.Dataframe` with a row for each combination `i, j` and then using groupby to perform the sum.

Consider the minimal example

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import numpy as np

arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']), 
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['i', 'j'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), index=index, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

borrowed from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html.

To sum over all `i` I can do

```
df.groupby(level=['j']).sum()
```

or equivalently

```
df.sum(level=['j'])
```

This works, but I don't like it for two reasons:

1. This is not extendible. Whenever I have a new "silent" index, I need to modify all sum which are in different places of my code.
2. I find it hard to understand. In my case `i` and `j` have a clear meaning, thus I want to write what I sum over explictly to get self-documenting code.

What I can do is something like

```
i = [x for x in df.index.names if x != 'first']
df.sum(level=i)
```

While this solves the first problem, I don't think the code gets any clearer.

I there some better pandas functionality or better suited (python) tool for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
df.groupby(df.index.droplevel('i')).sum() # groupby except index 'i'
```