# Pandas remove a column by averaging based on other column values

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Here is a model of the type of data I have:

```
    label1  label2  repetition     value
0        1       4           0  0.831011
1        1       9           0  0.698217
2        4       4           0  0.885272
3        4       9           0  0.009940
4        8       4           0  0.816476
5        8       9           0  0.069162
6        1       4           1  0.988980
7        1       9           1  0.892004
8        4       4           1  0.962106
9        4       9           1  0.367945
10       8       4           1  0.624772
11       8       9           1  0.694558
```

It can be generated like this:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
data = []
for repe in [0,1]:
    for label1 in [1,4,8]:
        for label2 in [4,9]:
            value = random.random()
            data.append([label1, label2, repe, value])

data=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['label1', 'label2', 'repetition', 'value'])
```

I would like to generate a new DataFrame with columns `label1`, `label2` and `value`, where value takes the average of all the repetitions.
This is a way to achieve it:

```
data2 = data.groupby(['label1', 'label2'])['value'].mean().reset_index()
```

However in my real case I have more label columns, so I think the code is not clear as the reader has to infer that the missing column `repetition` is the one that will be used for the average. Is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: You are actually averages across same values of `label1` & `label2` and not across `repetition`. So. I do not understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a very similar question here: [Use labels by which *not* to group in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507561/use-labels-by-which-not-to-group-in-pandas-groupby). My labels were a hierachical index though.

The answer I got was

```
df.groupby(df.index.droplevel('repetition')).mean()
```

which is better but still not really elegant. I usually use

```
df.groupby(df.columns.difference(['repetition']).mean()
```

which at least gets the intent across.

If you find a good way to this, let me know ;)

Comment: Thanks. This is much better than what I had. Let's wait and see if somebody comes up with something even more elegant.

Comment: The second solution is quite elegant however on pandas 1.2.5 the columns needs to be casted to a list so the following worked for me: 
`df.groupby(list(df.columns.difference(['repetition']))).mean()`